# Websocket app consuming from RESTful/transactional APIs

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I understand how to use Websockets when the server side app utilizing sockets is working directly with data stores, but what about when it's aggregating information from other APIs?

Say for instance if I have Node/Socket.io backing a web app but I want to pull data from Twitter or something similar that's going to give me a batch of data at a time, how do I keep the information flowing through the open sockets given the transactional nature of the other services?

Comment: Can you give an example of a scenario where you didn't found a solution? it's really common to make async requests with node.js and once the data comes back - send it via the socket.

Comment: Second @GuyS: What is the problem here? What is the difference for sending information via WebSocket whether you get this via another socket, REST call, as the result of a calculation etc.?